# Checking While Condition and Inner setInterval Condition

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```js
var conmath = "1000 - {{sum}}";
var re = /{{([^{}]+)}}/;
var m;
console.log('Conmath-Outside While: ' + conmath);
while (m == re.exec(conmath)) {
  console.log('M: ' + m);
  var mfld = m[1];
  console.log('MFld: ' + mfld);
  console.log('Conmath-Inside While: ' + conmath);
  var mult = "2";
  var mfldi = "field~~sum"
  var mfldtxt = '#field' + '\\~\\~' + mfld;
  console.log('MfldTxt ' + mfldtxt);
  waitmfld = $(mfldtxt).filter(function() {return $(this).attr('data-mult') == mult}); // set var global to use in other funcs
  console.log('Waitmfld: ', $(waitmfld));
  var wtime = 0;
  return; // temp - comment out to see infinite loop
  var waitForElement = setInterval(function(waitmfld, mfld) {
    console.log('Inside Wait');
    console.log('ClassCk: ' + $(waitmfld).hasClass('done'));
    if (wtime > 1500) { // stop wait after 2secs
      console.log('Ending Wait: ' , $(wait));
      clearInterval(waitForElement);
    }  
    if ($(waitmfld).hasClass('done')) {
      console.log('Wait Has Class');
      var mval = $(waitmfld).text();
      console.log('Mval-Wait: ' + mval); // should be 3
      var conmath = "1000 - 3"; // set conmath to check if can get out of while loop
      clearInterval(waitForElement);
    }
    wtime += 500;
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="field~~sum" class="reg" data-mult="1">something</span>
<span id="field~~sum" class="reg done" data-mult="2">3</span>
```

I am trying to update a variable (conmath) until it doesn't contain any more {{var}} variables.  I'm using while loop and a setInterval inside of that.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/billparti/oxej2s91/

```
    var conmath = "1000 - {{sum}}";
    var re = /{{([^{}]+)}}/;
    var m;
    console.log('Conmath-Outside While: ' + conmath);
    while (m == re.exec(conmath)) {
      var mfld = m[1];
      console.log('MFld: ' + mfld);
      console.log('Conmath-Inside While: ' + conmath);
      var mult = "2";
      var mfldi = "field~~sum"
      var mfldtxt = '#field' + '\\~\\~' + mfld;
      console.log('MfldTxt ' + mfldtxt);
      waitmfld = $(mfldtxt).filter(function() {return $(this).attr('data-mult') == mult}); // set var global to use in other funcs
      console.log('Waitmfld: ', $(waitmfld));
      var wtime = 0;
      return; // temp - comment out to see infinite loop
      var waitForElement = setInterval(function(waitmfld, mfld) {
        console.log('Inside Wait');
        console.log('ClassCk: ' + $(waitmfld).hasClass('done'));
        if (wtime > 1500) { // stop wait after 2secs
          console.log('Ending Wait: ' , $(wait));
          clearInterval(waitForElement);
        }  
        if ($(waitmfld).hasClass('done')) {
          console.log('Wait Has Class');
          var mval = $(waitmfld).text();
          console.log('Mval-Wait: ' + mval); // should be 3
          conmath = "1000 - 3"; // set conmath to check if can get out of while loop
          clearInterval(waitForElement);
        }
        wtime += 500;
      }, 500);
    }
```

Note: I put a temp return before the setInterval so you can see if there are other errors and it also prevents an infinite loop from happening.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us understand the problem, please use the Code Snippet tool integrated into StackOverflow instead of an external link to fiddle. Also, please leave in your code only parts relevant to your problem. It will also help if you explain what you are trying to achieve and what blocks you from that. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't assign a value to `m`.

Comment: @RAllen - ok I jumped through all of your hoops and added a code snippet as well, please read my description and look at the code running and you will see errors - I have no idea how to correct them.

Comment: @James - I set a condition in the while - I thought that's how you did it - you will have to show me.